# Android Toolbar Subtitlte to a String

Tags: java, android, xml, string, toolbar

I have a toolbar, but how can I set the subtitle to a string resource? 
I want that the subtitle is a string. How can I do this?

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setSubtitle(@string/test1);

    } 
}
```

My content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
         <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"    
           parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
           parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" 
/>

</resources>
```

My strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">Test</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string name="test1">Test1</string>
<string name="test2">Test2</string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since  `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`  you should be able to use

```
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(getString(R.string.test1));
```

`toolbar.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.test1));` should do it as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toolbar.setSubtitle(R.string.test1);`